# Wordpress Logged out code

Tags: wordpress, authentication, visibility

I'm fairly new to wordpress and am looking for code to show a login link on the top bar and also on the menu, the 'my account' page to only show for logged in users.

i can only find the coding is_user_logged_in() which is doing the reverse of what i'm looking for.

using the Menu Items Visibility Control plugin, unless there's a better solution out there?

Comment: You're question will probably be put on hold as off topic to Stack Overflow. But you can try "Theme My Login", its a plugin that allows you to do that. There's also " If Menu", which applies conditions to display menus. Best of luck!

Comment: I found a solution - Hide/Unhide Menu for Guest/Member plugin :)

Comment: Grand! All the best then! :)

Answer (score 1):

The function you cited should work fine for this use case.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Show the My Account link
} else {
    // Show the login button
}
```

Or, if you need to check if a user is NOT logged in:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Do something
}
```